# Query documents not defined in a Mongoose model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I query a Mongo collection called `interventions` with Mongoose's `findById` method on the `Intervention` model. The query returns all fields defined in the associated model.

A `student` field also exists in the `interventions` collection. Mongoose is not returning it. Presumably, this is because the complex `student` object (25-30 key/value pairs) is NOT defined in the Interventions model. I won't ever need to insert documents into the Interventions model.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const { Schema } = mongoose

const interventionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    abs_count_excused: { type: Number },
    abs_count_unexcused: { type: Number },
    abs_count_total: { type: Number },
    student_id: { type: Number, required: true }
  }
)

const Intervention = mongoose.model(
  'Intervention',
  interventionSchema,
  'interventions'
)
export default Intervention
```

**Is it possible to retrieve the `student` subdocument without defining it in the Interventions model?**

Thank you.

Comment: Would you need to update the `student` field at all?

Comment: Not through the Intervention model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can retrieve a value from MongoDB without having it as part of your Mongoose schema in some way. This seems like an opportunity for the [Mixed schema type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) for Mongoose.

Because your concern is translating the complex `student` document to a schema and you don't plan on updating it through the `Intervention` model, the drawback of the `Mixed` schema type doesn't apply. As such, you can add the `student` field to your schema like so:

```
const interventionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    abs_count_excused: { type: Number },
    abs_count_unexcused: { type: Number },
    abs_count_total: { type: Number },
    student_id: { type: Number, required: true },
    student: { type: Object }
  }
)
```